# Dual OS ubuntu with windows 8.1 install not working for Hp ac024tx

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

i have encountered a problem while trying to install ubuntu along with windows 8.1 in my hp ac024tx laptop. The option install ubuntu alondside windows was not available so i choose something else, then my windows partitions are not shown. I am unable to install ubuntu due to this problem. Please leave some answer that will help me install ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your BIOS config?...Should be on UEFI and CMOS for dual installing, before installing Ubuntu.
Now, your win partitions are not shown? or they lost in the process(Ubuntu takes all the space?)
Once the win partition does not appear, cant acces from Ubuntu to the Win disk, dont know what happened but i try to install Ubuntu again and just work.
If Ubuntu takes all, check if installing Win, or yourself, make extra partitions. Let Ubuntu do that Job, its very easy with default tool.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for reply i think the problem is due to dynamic partition in windows

Comment: when you solve it make a comment...good luck

Comment: Problem with installing ubuntu aside windiws was due to dynamic disk partitions. The problem has resolved by making the disk to basic